# Drupal 9 Ошибка установки темы

Tags: drupal, установка

Установил Drupal 9.1.9
Хотел попробовать установить другую тему Thex.
Drupal затребовал логин/пароль для FTP.
Дал и то и другое.
Начинает устанавливать и в конце вываливается с ошибкой:
Ошибка установки/обновления
File Transfer failed, reason: 'Cannot create directory /drupal/public_html/themes/thex'
В каталоге папка создается. Но она пустая.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил.
В файле /public_html/sites/default/settings.php нужно раскомментировать строку $settings['file_temp_path'] = '/tmp'; и убрать слэш перед "tmp"